# How to visualize boxes and labels with different min_thres values for different detection classes in tensorflow object detection api?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have  a trained modell with 3 different classes. When running the inference I want to visualize my detections via this method of:

```
def visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
image,
boxes,
classes,
scores,
category_index,
instance_masks=None,
instance_boundaries=None,
keypoints=None,
keypoint_scores=None,
keypoint_edges=None,
track_ids=None,
use_normalized_coordinates=False,
max_boxes_to_draw=20,
min_score_thresh=.5,
agnostic_mode=False,
line_thickness=4,
mask_alpha=.4,
groundtruth_box_visualization_color='black',
skip_boxes=False,
skip_scores=False,
skip_labels=False,
skip_track_ids=False):
```

However, every detection class is displayed with the same min_score_thresh, but I want to display class 1 objects with min_score_thresh=0.9, class2-objects with min_score_thresh=0.6 and class3-objects with mimin_score_thresh=0.2. Do you have any ideas how to do that?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the sample code to visualize the Bounding boxes.

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [42, 21]
  label_id_offset = 1
  image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()
  viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        image_np_with_detections,
        detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),
        detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy().astype(np.int32),
        detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy(),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        max_boxes_to_draw=200,
        min_score_thresh=.40,
        agnostic_mode=False)
  plt.subplot(2, 1, i+1)
  plt.imshow(image_np_with_detections)
```

Take a look at Tensorflow object detection API demo [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb)